# Can you leave Pool open across multiple different Map functions within Python's Multiprocessing Pool?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm wondering if you can leave a `multiprocessing.Pool` open across multiple different `map` functions? If this is possible, are there any pitfalls with such an approach?

My general use case would be to assign a pool to a class variable, such as `self.pool`, and then call this `self.pool` across various different `map` functions within the class - e.g., `self.pool.map(func, args)`. My goal is to minimize the overhead of closing down and then restarting each `pool` of workers, such that I just keep them open indefinitely and pass them `self.pool.map` jobs as I need it.

One potential pitfall I can see would be that I would need to remember to close the `self.pool` within the class once I'm done using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the pool many times. Your design is a good one. Sure, you have to close, but the enclosing class could itself have a `def close(self):` function that does that, and make that a requirement of using the class. You could even make that class a context manager if you want to. The need to catch exceptions and close things in a finally block is standard fare for python programming.

As an example,

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import threading

class MyClassWithPool:

    def __init__(self, workers=None):
        self._mp_pool_lock = threading.Lock()
        self._pool = None
        if workers is None:
            self._pool_count = min(2, int(mp.cpu_count() * .50))
        else:
            self._pool_count = workers
        # initialize your other stuff...

    @property
    def mp_pool(self):
        with self._mp_pool_lock:
            if self._pool is None:
                self._pool = mp.Pool(self._pool_count)
        return self._pool

    def close(self):
        with self._mp_pool_lock:
            if self._pool:
                self._pool.close()
                self._pool = None
        # ... any other cleanup ...

    def __del__(self):
        self.close()
    
def do_some_stuff(i):
    return i
    
def do_other_stuff(i):
    return i

def main():
    my_data = MyClassWithPool()
    try:
        result_1 = my_data.mp_pool.map(do_some_stuff, range(5))
        print(result_1)
        result_2 = my_data.mp_pool.map(do_other_stuff, range(99))
        print(result_2)
    finally:
        my_data.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Can you provide an example / link to illustrate handling exception cases with this type of design? I'd like to try and incorporate that my code.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for adding an example! Very helpful!